# About implementation of abstract/concrete graphs in C++

Tags: c++, memory, inheritance, graph, reference

I am writing a program that works with graphs. I am dealing with two types of graphs : "abstract graphs", which consist in abstract vertices with edges, and "planar graphs", in which the vertices have coordinates x,y in the plane (actually I am working with a complex affix z but it does not matter).

I have elected to write an (abstract) Vertex class and a derived class Planar_Vertex as follows in my Vertex.h file - this is not precisely my code, I made it slightly simpler and "translated" it from French ;)

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex();
    int get_label();
    void set_label(int label);
    void add_neighbor(int label);
    bool is_neighbor(int label);
    // etc
protected:
    int _label;
    std::vector<int> _list_neighbors;
};


class Planar_Vertex : public Vertex
{
    complex<double> _affix;
public:
    Planar_Vertex();
    Planar_Vertex(Vertex& V, complex<double> affix);
    complex<double> get_affix();
    void set_affix(complex<double> affix);
};
```

Here's my main question. I would like my Planar_Vertex(Vertex& V, complex affix) constructor to have the following effects : 1. Output a Planar_Vertex whose label and list of neighbors are the same as V, and whose affix is given. So far, easy. 2. I would like V to be precisely the abstract Vertex underlying this new object. In other words, if in my main.cpp file I wrote, say,

```
Vertex V1;
...
Planar_Vertex V2(V1,z)
```

then I would like that a use of set_label() on V2 will also affect V1 (for example). The way I see it is, in this constructor, I would like to say something like: make the address of V (in memory) the same as that of the Planar_Vertex constructed (and free the memory previously allocated to V). Apparently it is not possible to change the location of a variable in memory though, so I don't know what to do. I am relatively new to C++ and I'm getting lost reading about placement new, std::move, rvalues etc. Does anybody see how to do what I want?

**[Edit : To summarize, I want to be able to build an object of the derived class on top of an object of the base class that has already been built.]**

Okay, now since I told you guys that much about my implementation of graphs, I thought I'd tell you the rest so you can give me your opinion about it, I hope you don't mind. Obviously you don't have to read the following, if you know the answer to my first question that'd be cool already. So as I told you we're dealing with "abstract graphs", which will consist in abstract vertices, and planar graphs, which consist in planar vertices.

Here's what my Graph.h file looks like:

```
class Graph
{
public:
    Graph();
    virtual ~Graph();
    virtual std::vector<Vertex*> get_list_vertices();
    void add_edge(int label1, int label2);
    virtual void add_vertex(Vertex&);
    // etc
};

class Abstract_Graph : public Graph
{
    std::vector<Vertex*> _list_vertices;
public:
    Abstract_Graph();
    ~Abstract_Graph();
    std::vector<Vertex*> get_list_vertices();
    void add_vertex(Vertex& V);
    // etc
};

class Planar_Graph : public Graph
{
    std::vector<Planar_Vertex*> _list_planar_vertices;
public:
    Planar_Graph();
    ~Planar_Graph();
    std::vector<Vertex*> get_list_vertices();
    std::vector<Planar_Vertex*> get_list_planar_vertices();
    void add_vertex(Planar_Vertex& V);
    // etc
};
```

My idea is that the base class Graph will never be instanciated, but I will be able to implement "abstract graph operations" as functions of this base class and they will work on both Abstract_Graph and Planar_Graph objects. This is made possible thanks to the purely virtual function get_list_vertices. Is this a reasonable way to do things? What would you have done?

Thank you very much for for answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference (or a pointer) to a Vertex object in your Planar_Vertex class to do what you want if I understood you.
Cut down demo:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Vertex {
    int value;
};

struct Planar_Vertex: public Vertex {
    Vertex& vr;
    Planar_Vertex(Vertex& v): vr(v) {}
};

int main()
{
    Vertex v;
    v.value = 1;
    std::cout << v.value << std::endl;

    Planar_Vertex p = Planar_Vertex(v);
    p.vr.value = 2;
    std::cout << v.value << std::endl;
}
```

If you use a reference, it *must* be initialized in the constructor initialization list. If you use a pointer, you have more flexibility in how you initialize it, but have to worry about null pointers everywhere.

In both cases, you're responsible for making sure that the Vertex outlives the Planar_Vertex.

(Another option is to have a plain Vertex (not a reference or pointer) as a member of Planar_Vertex – you initialize it via Planar_Vertex's constructor, and use it wherever you need. This takes care of the lifetime requirements, but might not be possible in your code.)

For your second part, I don't see anything fundamentally wrong, but it's hard to have an opinion just with what you posted. Inheritance is one way to do this, another would be to use templates. Which one is more appropriate depends on the exact requirements (and your familiarity with both these concepts).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did think about writing two independent classes Vertex and Planar_Vertex like you describe. However this is not what I want to do because the point of inheritance is that I only have to write the abstract functions once (such as add_neighbor etc). Additionnally, I will get the same issue with my graphs if I implement things that way. It just seems to me that inheritance is the natural thing to do here, but I could be wrong of course. As for templates, I know nothing about them.

Comment: The example above works just as well if `Planar_Vertex: public Vertex`. If you want to build a `Planar_Vertex` "around"/"on top of" a `Vertex`, you "can't" or you "don't have a choice" depending on how you see it. Every `Planar_Vertex` object is built on top of a Vertex - so you already have that. But you can't build a `Planar_Vertex` on top of a random `Vertex` that has already been constructed.

Comment: (In other words, you can use a reference or pointer to a Planar_Vertex everywhere you would use a Vertex.)

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I want to do, you summarized it well. I want to build a Planar_Vertex on top of a random Vertex that has already been constructed. Is there really no way at all around this? (Allow me to edit my post to summarize my main question in these words)

Comment: No, that can't work. Think about the memory allocation for a bit. If you create two Vertex objects one after the other, chances are they'll be one besides the other in memory. If you want to tack something "on top of" the first, where do you put its extra data members?

Comment: Well, for instance I would like to move everything in memory. change the memory location of the Vertex that has already been built, and then build something on top of it.

Comment: Moving the original vertex would invalidate all references to it, losing all advantages you might have had with this strategy.

Comment: i.e., naively, something like 'Planar_Vertex V1; ... (define V1 using V) ...; delete V; V=(Vertex)V1;

Comment: "Moving the original vertex would invalidate all references to it, losing all advantages you might have had with this strategy." you're absolutely right. this seems doomed to failure...

Comment: You get everything from your previous comment without doing anything, just using inheritance - except `delete v` (but you could do that if you use pointers) and re-seating references that originally pointed at `v` (that you can't do, unless you use double indirection everywhere, and you'd have hairy lifetime issues at best).

Comment: @Mat: What lifetime issues? Everybody points to a forwarder, which points to (and owns) the real vertex.

Comment: With (plain) pointers, the compiler can't help you at all with the "owning" part. So you are responsible for knowing exactly what points to live objects and what doesn't, what needs to be deleted and what doesn't, etc. (i.e. lifetime issues). Smart pointers can help.